# Is "scopperloit" a real word?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

> Bysshe, Bysshe, Bysshe! What are we going to do about you? I hope
>   you'll pardon this mesonoxian and inaniloquent lamprophony from a
>   nihilarian pronk; it is not so much a phenakist scopperloit as it is a
>   finnimbrun, an infinite floccinaucinihilipilification ([The Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/audio/2011/may/20/essay-poetry-translation-rabindranath-tagore))

I found it, as comment, in The Guardian. After a lot of efforts to decipher its meaning, I encountered some hard trouble problem in searching for "scopperloit."

In Google "define scopperloit" does not produce serious hits.

Can anybody explain the meaning of "scopperloit"?

Comment: http://www.drbilllong.com/2008Words/WeirdIII.html Not sure if this is general reference since it is such an obscure, obsolete word.

Comment: Aren’t you going to also ask us about the equally mysterious *mesonoxian, inaniloquent, lamprophony, nihilarian, phenakist, finnimbrun,* and *floccinaucinihilipilification*, too? Or shall we expect those as separate forthcoming questions?

Comment: Why the heck is "nihilarian" there when we already have "nihilist" ?? Even "nihilistic" is not needed, still it's kept like hoarder's garbage. **Too much irregularity and unusualness** which makes this language really weird, making us vigilant about that these kinda words aren't mysterious, they're simply unrequired "weed" stuff that must be discarded before it creates confusion & self-doubts in it's users. What happens when you collect & ultimately fill your house with numerous same/similar things ? You must stay out to keep them in. That's what's been happening to English since so long now.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it’s a “real word”, whatever that is supposed to mean. The OED says it is *dialectal*, rather than *obsolete*.  Per the OED, ***scopperloit*** is play that is romping, rude, indelicate in nature.  It seems to correspond to words like *horseplay* or *roughhousing* in contemporary English.

> **ˈscopperloit**. *dial*.
>
> Also 7 **skoppoloit**, -**lot**.
>
> Etymology: Of obscure origin: cf. **scobberlotcher** and **scoterlope** *v*.
>
> (See quots.)
>
> - 1691 Ray *S. & E.C.* Wds. 111 ― A Scopperloit, a time of idleness, a play-time.
> - 1787 in Grose *Prov. Gloss.*
> - 1878 S. H. Miller & Skertchly *Fenland* iv. 131 ― *Skoppolot*, *Skoppoloit*, romping, rude, indelicate play.

Comment: +1 I couldn't find any evidence for the rough-play definition. (Note to self: get a dead-tree OED.)

Comment: @JLG No, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a definition for this obsolete word in any online dictionary. However, a li'l digging unearthed the following references in a couple of esoteric catalogues:

From [The Routledge Dictionary of Historical Slang (1973)](http://books.google.com/books?id=0voNAAAAQAAJ&dq=scopperloit%20dictionary):

> ... the North Country and East Anglian *scopperloit, soppoloit*, **a time of idleness or of play** ...

From [An Universal Etymological Dictionary (1759)](http://books.google.com/books?id=jj3vK7SlEL4C&dq=scopperloit%20dictionary&q=scopperloit#v=snippet&q=scopperloit):

> A *Scopperloit*, a Time of Idleness, a Play-Time.

It also finds mention in an [investigation of the word *scobberlotcher*](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-sco3.htm):

> The Oxford English Dictionary points, tentatively, to two old words as possible antecedents. One is the eastern English regional *scopperloit*, **a time of idleness** (*perhaps from Dutch leuteren*, to idle, the source of English loiter).

A few hits on Google [such as this one](http://obsoleteword.blogspot.com/2007_11_01_archive.html) go a step further by claiming that scopperloit can also mean "*rude and rough-housing play*". I couldn't find any sources to corroborate this nuance. (Edit: tchrist's answer confirms that the OED includes this additional definition.)